# Toggle a div closed if a #something is present in a URL

Tags: jquery

How can i toggle a div closed using jquery ie hide the box below (close it) if #something is present in the URL http://www.mydomain.co.uk/index.php#something

```
<div id="feature">content</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    if(window.location.hash.indexOf('something') !== -1) {
        $('div#feature').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By checking the `window.location.hash`.

```
if (window.location.hash == "something") $("#featured").hide();
```